# How do I organize labels on top or bottom, or right, or left?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1

How do I organize the labels in the layout, for example, I want the label Year to be on the top of the Acres. I tried variety ways to do this using the Label Manager but can't seem to get it right  Anyone have a better or suggest of a good way to solution this ?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

Is there a good reason why two label classes are being used? When labels are in a separate class, there is no guarantee they will be placed near each other.

Why not just use one class with a label expression such as this?

```
[YEAR] & vbNewLine & "<CLR red = '255'>" & [AREA] & "</CLR>"
```

See the [help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-text/formatting-tags-available-in-arcmap.htm) for more information on formatting tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on the layer and then "Convert Labels to Annotation". Then you can manually drag the labels to where you want.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer, but it appears that there still is not a suitable resolution for this.  My workaround was to create the label classes in the order that I want them to appear.

So, I have a "Year" class and then an "Area" class.  Like so:

[image]

The result is:

[image]